# Grouping Data with counts

Tags: c#, linq

I have this simple test program also available at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NAyrkn).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var products = ProductInfo.Products;
        var codes = products.Select(s => s.Code).Distinct().ToList();
        var grouped = products.GroupBy(g => new
        {
            g.Origin,
            g.Destination
        })
        .Select(s => new ProductSummary
        {
            Origin = s.Key.Origin,
            Destination = s.Key.Destination
        })
        .ToList();

        Console.Write("Code ");
        foreach (var i in grouped)
        {
            Console.Write($"{i.Origin}-{i.Destination} ");
        }
    }

    public class ProductSummary
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }

        public string Destination { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductInfo
    {
        public string Origin { get; set; }

        public string Destination { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public static List<ProductInfo> Products => new List<ProductInfo>{
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "LONDON", Destination = "USA", Code = "M1"}, 
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "LONDON", Destination = "USA", Code = "M1"}, 
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "LONDON", Destination = "USA", Code = "M2"}, 
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "LONDON", Destination = "USA", Code = "M1"}, 
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "LONDON", Destination = "USA", Code = "M2"}, 
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "USA", Destination = "LONDON", Code = "M1"}, 
        new ProductInfo{Origin = "USA", Destination = "LONDON", Code = "M3"}};
    }
}
```

My desired output would be:

| Code | LONDON-USA | USA-LONDON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | 3 | 1 |
| M3 | 0 | 1 |
| M2 | 2 | 0 |

I can't seem to figure out how to group to iterate and get that result.

If someone can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What about those with code `M2`?

Comment: Yes those also need to be there.

Comment: Do you just need output like the one in your sample as a string or do you need actual lists of objects grouped by `Code` to do something with it afterward?

Comment: I am going to dump into csv so lists would work but I am thinking it would be many loops to get the layout as in example.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple return routes under the same `Code`? Like Code (M1) | LONDON-USA | USA-LONDON | PARIS-TOKYO | TOKYO-PARIS? Do you always have to display the count for the return route as well or is it possible to have the one-way route in this table?

Comment: Yes it is there can be more routes.  This is begging to become more of a custom pivot table maybe?  This data can come from anywhere not just a db hence the hardcoded list for demo.

Comment: There are tons of questions about LINQ + pivoting. That's because there's no built-in method and, hence, no standard solution.

Comment: It seems pretty weird way to query, at least for me. For me I'd suggest a query with 3 columns - `Code`, `Route`, `Count`, then code your logic to print it the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

For supporting an unknown selection of `Origin` and `Destination` combination (both in content and count), I would suggest creating a `Dictionary` where `Code` is the key and an `IEnumerable<ProductSummary>` is the value. (This requires `ProductSummary` to be expanded with member `int Code`).

```csharp
public class ProductSummary
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ProductSummary>> grouped = ProductInfo.Products
    .GroupBy(product => product.Code)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.Key,
        gr => gr.GroupBy(product => ( product.Origin, product.Destination ))
            .Select(travelGr => 
                new ProductSummary { Origin = travelGr.Key.Item1, Destination = travelGr.Key.Item2, Count = travelGr.Count() }));
```

Using this approach, though, you will not get entries where `Count == 0`. I.e. for the example input you have provided, this approach will produce the following key/value pairs:

```csharp
M1:
    LONDON-USA: 3
    USA-LONDON: 1
M2:
    LONDON-USA: 2
M3:
    USA-LONDON: 1
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/brPaI9).
Example fiddle including tabular visualization [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePzFsQ).

Comment: Appreciate the answer but what about getting the layout I require would that be multiple loops? As I had a similar query working but could not get the layout.

Comment: @AliK With "layout", do you really mean populating each dictionary entry with all possible combinations of `Origin`/`Destination`? (E.g. adding a `ProductSummary { Origin = "USA", Destination = "LONDON", Count = 0 }` to the entry with key `"M2"`, and adding a `ProductSummary { Origin = "LONDON", Destination = "USA", Count = 0 }` to the entry with key `"M3"`)? Or do you mean keeping the content of `grouped` as is, but displaying the results in a tabular format where the non-existing `ProductSummary`s for a key is displayed in the cell as `0`?

Comment: I mean layout as per my example table in question.  Code, Routes along the top and code, count per route under it.

Comment: @AliK I have added a fiddle for displaying the result in a table (see bottom of post). Does that accomplish what you need?

Comment: greatly appreciated I can take fit from here I have been thinking about ways of doing this for hours and kept coming up with crazy looping.